# как удалить записи из table

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть две таблицы:

```
--First Table
CREATE TABLE SimulatedResult.SimulatedResultGroup
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    GroupName VARCHAR(255)
);

--Second Table
CREATE TABLE SimulatedResult.EventForSimulateGroup
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EventId int,
    SimulatedResultGroupId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SimulatedResult.SimulatedResultGroup(Id)
);
```

хочу удалить записи с первой таблицы(SimulatedResultGroup) и все записи которые связаны с ним во втором таблице

Comment: Следует указать, что не дает исполнить Ваше желание. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: кажется вы не поняли мой вопрос

Comment: Тем более. *(5 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы автоматизировать этот процесс стоит повесить триггер на процесс удаления первой таблицы.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_DEL
ON SimulatedResult.SimulatedResultGroup
FOR DELETE
AS
     delete from SimulatedResult.EventForSimulateGroup
     where SimulatedResultGroupId in (select id from DELETED );
```

Теперь при удалении записи из **SimulatedResultGroup** будут автоматически удаляться записи из **EventForSimulateGroup**

Answer (score 2):

Вы либо должны добавить во второй таблице внешнему ключу свойство `ON DELETE CASCADE`, и тогда при удалении данных из первой таблицы будут автоматически удаляться из второй, либо писать запрос на удаление с сравнением полей.